# Reference to file in onChange vs onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application that opens a filepicker and calls a method (`handleFileChosen`) when a file is picked (`onChange`). I would like that method (`handleFileChosen`) to be called when a button is clicked (`onClick`), rather than when the file is initially chosen.

Currently my code looks like this:

render() {

```
let fileReader;

const handleFileRead = (e) => {
    // do stuff
};

const handleFileChosen = (file) => {
    fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onloadend = handleFileRead
    fileReader.readAsText(file)
};

if(this.state.loading === true) return <div>...exporting file</div>;

return (

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" onChange={e => handleFileChosen(e.target.files[0])}></input>
      <label class="custom-file-label" htmlFor="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onClick={e => handleFileChosen(e.target.files[0])}>Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My issue is that the `handleFileChosen` method call works fine when it is triggered by the `onChange` event, but when triggered by the `onClick` event on the button it causes a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error.

How can I fix this so that the onClick event successfully calls `handleFileChosen`?

Comment: It is because the `e` is the event object. The variable doesn't scope itself to both. They each have their own event object. Are you using class or function-based components?

Comment: I get that, but if I remove the onChange event from the filepicker it still doesn't work. Updating my code snippet to answer your question

Comment: hold `fileReader` in state as `this.fileReader` and invoke the methods you want inside the click handler. You might want some boolean logic to control whether or not the buttons hould have any behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection between the input and button element. You have to wait until the file has been loaded to store in a local state. Then you can use it in your button onClick callback.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this isn't quite possible, because the handler expect an object that have an array of files inside it, and this is only achievable by using an especific input which the type is **files**. Although, you could transform this input to be the shape you want trough css